# OpenGLES2 iOS: How best to stream vertex animation for dynamic terrain?

Tags: objective-c, ios, optimization, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm writing an app that creates a dynamic 640*480 terrain (changes every frame). Each terrain is stored in a raw data file which represents a string of (float) height values. So far I can read the files in sequence into memory, and dynamically create a mesh based on height values each frame (and the framerate is actually reasonable), but I am maxing out at around 20 frames before my app quits with no error or stack trace.

I suspect that I am approaching this incorrectly. How would I stream this data so that I don't have to hold each frame in memory?

Here is a section from my data class, which holds a collection of terrains:

```
- (void)addModelWithID:(int)modelID;
{
    NSString* resourcePath  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString* fileName      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"depth_%i.raw", modelID];
    NSString* fullPath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    if (!myData)
      return;

    const float *data = [myData bytes];

    int meshWidth               = 640;
    int meshHeight              = 480;

    Model *kModel = [[Model alloc] init];

    int indicesPtr  = 0;
    int depthPtr = 2;

    for (int y=0;y<meshHeight;y++)    // Loop through y pixels
        {
            for (int x=0;x<meshWidth;x++)   // Loop through x pixels
            {
                // Set up vertex positions
                int index  = y*meshWidth+x;
                float xpos = ((float)x/(float)(meshWidth-1)) - 0.5f;
                float ypos = ((float)y/(float)(meshHeight-1)) - 0.5f;
                float zpos = (float)data[index];

                kModel.vertices1[index*3+0] = xpos;
                kModel.vertices1[index*3+1] = ypos;
                kModel.vertices1[index*3+2] = zpos;

                // Create a new index based on whether the current line is even or odd (flipped horizontally if odd)
                int _index = (y%2==0) ? index : (y*meshWidth) + ((meshWidth-1)-x); 

                //Create the first index
                kModel.indices[indicesPtr++] = _index;

                // Create the second index
                if ((x<meshWidth-1) || (x==meshWidth-1 && y==meshHeight-2))
                    kModel.indices[indicesPtr++] = _index+meshWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    // Add the model to the data object
    [Models addObject:kModel];
    [kModel release];
}
```

And my draw code (each frame I call a different terrain, hopefully up to 500 or so, but I max out at ~20:

```
{
    ...
        Model *kModel = [kData.kinectModels objectAtIndex:sequenceCurrentFrame];

        glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)kModel.vertices1);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&modelViewProjection.data[0]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, kModel.numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)kModel.indices);
    ...
}
```

Thanks a million for your help,

Josh

Comment: You should definitively consider writing a vertex shader for morphing the terrain for you. Besides that, how do you release the memory of each terrain chunk?

Comment: As far as I understand, I can't release the memory of each terrain chunk because I need to cycle through them at ~30fps. So if I release it then I would have to load the terrain file back in each frame which would be very slow, no? Is it possible to write a vertex shader for the depth of the terrain? It does seem silly to create the x and y values every time, since they aren't changing, but I don't really know how to begin sending the Z position to the shader. Any tips?

Comment: An aside: use `NSData`'s `NSDataReadingMappedAlways` option (with `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` as a drop-in substitution for your current `dataWithContentsOfFile:`); that'll cause the file to be memory mapped rather than loaded, so you'll get a pointer you can use exactly as if the entire file were loaded but the OS will handle what part of the file is actually in memory and what remains on disk as a caching task, automatically handling overall memory footprint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your height data in a texture and then use `texture2D` function in vertex shader to modify the current height of the vertex.

With this setup you can have single mesh and simply adjust the height of each vertex by the value stored in the texture.

If you are sure that you are GPU-bound, the texture format used for looking up the height data can also be further optimized. Say your  heightmap ranges from `0-255`, given the `GL_RGBA` format you can use the same texture for rendering up to 4 frames (first frame read the height from the red component, next frame from the blue component, etc.). 
Making the backing texture twice as big (1280x960) will further allow you to store up to 16 frames within a single texture.
Another thing worth mentioning with regard to textures is that using the native format for your GPU can also bolster performance in both GPU/IO-bound scenarios. For iDevices this format is [PVRTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PVRTC).

I really think that the problem is just the allocation of 300k+ vertices each frame alone ... that adds up to 640 * 480 * 3 * 4 = **3 686 400 bytes** allocated every frame and you didn't mention after how many frames you stop allocating the memory (wait... *do you?*). That's way too much for such resource constrained environment.

Comment: Thank you arul, this is most enlightening. I'll certainly implement the texture2D idea. At the moment I am keeping all the data in memory simply because I only want to read from disk once. Clearly that isn't working. Ultimately, I want to play a sequence of any length. My idea was to concatenate all the object files into one, but how would I go about streaming a file like that from disk as you would, say, a 3Gb movie file? Each file just contains a list of 640*480 floats. Figure 3 minutes of animation at 24fps and you're getting into about that size. Isn't streaming the only option?

Comment: Yes it is, but you need to stream in only the important data, which in this case is the heightfield map. The theoretical IO-throughput needed is 29.4912MB/s (isn't that too much for iDevices?). I think that storing the height info as floats is overkill. Assuming you're interfacing with Kinect, you get the depth info with 13-bits precision, and the remaining 19-bits are wasted. Try implementing the texture2D lookup method and then profile the code to find out where the bottleneck is (I bet on IO-throughput).

Comment: Great, thank you so much for your help. So, just to be clear: a) Rewrite the Kinect raw files to only use much smaller data types (unsigned short, perhaps?) b) Stream the data in using the NSDataReadingMappedAlways option that Tommy suggested and c) use texture2D method to pass the height data to the vertex shader. Does that sound about right? Can I dump the contents of the NSDataReadingMappedAlways directly into here:? `glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)vertices);`

Comment: You still need to generate the mesh, but this time you can set the variable `float zpos` to `0.0f` since you will change it in the vertex shader. Then you need to take the depth data of the first frame and upload it to the GPU with `glTexImage2D` and then just  `glTexSubImage2D` the texture with the new frame data. (The depth data should be in the form of preprocessed PVRTC texture files for best performance.)